where to find my Google project's path for Google DLP
probably very stupid question but in the following code
I can't find what is my project path in Google DLP. Where can I find this path in Google console (or any other way)?
dlp = google.cloud.dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient()
parent = dlp.project_path('WHERE CAN I FIND WHAT GOES HERE???')


As per documentation, project_path takes the project's ID and returns the full resource path for that project.
You can find the project's ID in GCP Dashboard (you should have a widget containing the project's details) and in the path when you navigate the GCP console (you will always have a query parameter like project=your-project-id.
